# Does sklearn's implementation of PCA preserve order of input?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

Let's say this is how I do my PCA with sklearns `sklearn.decomposition.PCA`:

```
def doPCA(arr):
    scaler =  StandardScaler()
    scaler.fit(arr)
    arr =scaler.transform(arr)
    pca =PCA(n_components=2)
    X = pca.fit_transform(arr)
    return X
```

My current understanding is that I get an output array of the same length, but each sample is now of dimension 2.

Now, I am interested where a value in my original array `arr` ended up after the PCA.

---

My question is:

Can I assume that `X[i]`  corresponds to `arr[i]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you obtain as `X`, which is `U[:, :n_components]*S[:n_components]`, in your code are the PCA loadings on the first `n_components`. To understand why `X[i]` should correspond to `arr[i]`, let us see what loadings mean.

**Loadings**

Imagine the eigen vectors to be basis vectors for the new dimensions of order `n_components`. The loadings help define where each of the data points lie on this new dimension space. In other words, the original data points from the full feature space projected on to the reduced dimensional space. These are coefficients in linear combination (`np.dot(X, n_components)`) predicting the original full set of features by the (standardized) components.

So you can assume that `X[i]` corresponds to `arr[i]`.